# Filtering out the first rating of multiple ratings

Tags: mysql, sql

I work for a company that provides support and I have been asked to find out if customer satisfaction ratings drop if a user has seen the same auto response more than one time in their ticket history. So far, I have pulled the users who have seen the same auto response or 'macro' more than one time, the name of the macro, the count of the times they have seen it in their ticket history, and the rating and the rating:

```
SELECT user_name,  macro_name, COUNT(*), rating
FROM macros_used m
JOIN cases c
ON c.case_number = m.case_number
join ratings r
on r.case_number = c.case_number
where user_name <> ''
GROUP BY user_name, macro_name
HAVING COUNT(macro_name) > 1
```

I'm not sure if I am pulling the rating properly, I may need to pull all cases in their case history and date to get a rating for each case.

My question is, is there a way to filter out the first rating provided for the first time a user has seen a macro used since the first time they see it, it will not be a duplicate. I am trying to see if user ratings go down due to duplicate macros.

Comment: this query will not run unless you add "rating" in the GROUP BY, so no, you are not pulling rating properly. Yes, you will need to pull dates since you need to know how rating changes over the time. Would be nice if you provided at least some samples of data.

Comment: @user2065377: It will run in MySQL.  MySQL will return the first rating it encounters (essentially a random one.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use subqueries to find the first and the last rating for a case with that particular macro:

```
select  cm.*
,       first_rating.rating as first_rating
,       last_rating.rating as last_rating
from    (
        select  c.user_name
        ,       m.macro_name
        ,       count(*) as macro_usage_count
        from    cases c
        join    macros_used m
        on      m.fk_case_number = c.pk_case_number
        group by 
                c.user_name
        ,       m.macro_name
        having  count(m.macro_name) > 1
        ) cm
join    (
        select  r.rating
        from    cases c2
        join    macros_used m2
        on      m2.fk_case_number = c2.pk_case_number
                and c2.user_name = cm.user_name
                and m2.macro_name= cm.macro_name
        join    ratings r2
        on      r2.pk_case_number = c2.case_number
        order by
                r.date_submitted
        limit   1
        ) first_rating
join    (
        select  r.rating
        from    cases c2
        join    macros_used m2
        on      m2.fk_case_number = c2.pk_case_number
                and c2.user_name = cm.user_name
                and m2.macro_name= cm.macro_name
        join    ratings r2
        on      r2.pk_case_number = c2.case_number
        order by
                r.date_submitted desc
        limit   1
        ) last_rating
where   m.user_name <> ''
```

Comment: Thank you. A few things I should have provided, The user_name field is only in the cases table (pk_case_number, user_name, created at [case date]), the macro_name field is only in the macros_used table (fk_case_number, macro_name), and the ratings are only in the ratings table (pk_case_number, rating, date_submitted [date for the rating]).

Comment: @user2770466: Answer updated.  The subqueries search all ratings for all cases that have the macro.  You could simplify them if you knew every case had a rating.